# Where MS Word stores the list of synonyms?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

Right-click on any word in MS Word presents a list of synonyms.

Where is the complete list of all these words?

Can I add my own words this list?

Is this list accessible with VBA?

Comment: I misread the question. You're talking about (for example) Microsoft's  English thesaurus?

Comment: Yes, synonyms and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is accessible (to the best of my knowledge) through VBA. But you can add a website to it as a resource for thesaurus. For this purpose hit `Ctrl+Click` which opens Research tab. Then at the bottom go for `Research Options...` . There you can `Add Services...` to your references. Read [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-change-research-services-b862efc5-9a7b-4f88-a23d-93712d6e4397)

Manually adding a word to it like what you do in word Dictionary? I don't know any way to do that.

This would be helpful for other people: [Adding a custom dictionary](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322198/how-to-add-a-custom-dictionary-in-word)